# Change Bootstrap grid pixels size

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering if there is a way to change the default pixel size allocated for the grid system in Bootstrap.
For example `xs` is used for screens <768px but I would like to change that to be <480 for example.
Can this be done?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) pretty much everything before you download bootstrap.
Just [find the breakpoint](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) you want and change it's value, then download the package!

Alternatively you can download the [SASS/LESS](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) version and mess with the variables yourself.

I'd go with the latter if you already work with a preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

Just search in bootstrap.css for

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
```